# Sagepay: Payment Authorised and Then Failed

Tags: opayo

I'm using Server/InFrame integration, and according to Sagepay support, there are (rare) occasions when we get a notification about a successful payment (via an OK status), but this is then later failed. This can happen, according to Sagepay support, when they haven't been able to contact the bank properly.

I'm unable to find details about this in the documentation at http://www.sagepay.co.uk/file/1161/download-document/SERVERProtocolandIntegrationGuidelinesV3%200.pdf?token=0eZCcKj0tm33YeZ4gfrk4pHPaLClQnRcq3_vXsISjHI . The closest thing I see is in Step 12, 
 when SagePay sends batch files to the bank

```
If transactions  are rejected, we correct any errors and resubmit them for you.
```

What happens, in terms of status codes sent to the notification url, in a case when this batch fails, or there is some other error after the "OK" is sent to the notification url? Is there any official documentation to handle this case, or similar cases when a payment is "OK", but then later fails?

Edit: I'm seeing that the simulator doesn't seem to handle this case either. Is there a way to properly test/simulate this case, when OK is sent, but then later failed?

Answer (score 1):

The only reason you would receive a mixed message, such as Error/Failed on My Sage Pay but OK via Notification URL, is if an error occured during the notiication which returned an error/invalid response.

If the notification response via the Notification URL is interrupted i.e. browser refresh/closed etc Sage Pay may pick this up as error after the authorisation from the bank has been received as OK. We will then send Error via Notification URL to confirm the transaction has failed.

We'll send the notification several times until we receive a successful response/handshake from you in which you confirm the Status, StatusDetail and RedirectURL.

This scenario does not occur often however if you are able to provide a TXID example, our contact details can be found via http://www.sagepay.co.uk/contact, within 72 hours of the transaction being posted, we can investigate the reason for failure against the transaction logs.

Sage Pay Support

Comment: Please stop posting your tech support info. That's not what StackOverflow is for.